# Error with insert and reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an error in this code

```
void f(list<CClass*> mylist,CP* Database,string namePoi){
//some code
list <CClass*>::reverse_iterator ite;
            for (ite=mylist.rbegin(); ite!= mylist.rend(); ite++) {
                    mylist.insert(++ite,Database->getPointer(namePoi));//compiler error
                }
}
```

The error is
 : no matching function for call to 'std::list::insert(std::list::reverse_iterator&, CPOI*)'
the line`Database->getPointer(namePoi)`  is giving the right output but I think I m not using the right `insert` command because when I use a normal iterator(not reverse_iterator), it works perfect.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list::insert` only takes `iterator`s, not `reverse_iterator`s.  You can convert the `reverse_iterator` to an `iterator` by calling `base` on it:

```
mylist.insert((++ite).base(), Database->getPointer(namePoi));
```

Comment: Thanks problem solved